# Asp.net RegularExpressionValidator for specific digits

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Html:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSasiNo" runat="server" Width="250px" MaxLength="17"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="zorunlu" ValidationGroup="kaskoTeklifSayfasi" Display="Dynamic" ID="rangevalidator1" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtSasiNo" ErrorMessage="Enter number characters only (8 or 17)" ValidationExpression="^\d{8}$|^\d{17}$""></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSasiNo" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="kaskoTeklifSayfasi" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSasiNo" CssClass="zorunlu">Please enter Number.</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

If value as below **ok**

```
12345678    // This is 8 characters
12345678901234567    // This is 17 characters
```

However if value as below **not ok**

```
1 // 1 characters

123456 // 6 characters 

123456789 // 9 characters 

1234567890123456 // 16 characters
```

RegularExpressionValidator **only** should work for **8 character** and **17 character**

If try below

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="zorunlu" ValidationGroup="kaskoTeklifSayfasi" Display="Dynamic" ID="rangevalidator1" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtSasiNo" ErrorMessage="Enter number characters only (8 or 17)" ValidationExpression="^\d{8}$|^\d{17}$""></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

or

If i try below

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="zorunlu" ValidationGroup="kaskoTeklifSayfasi" Display="Dynamic" ID="rangevalidator1" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtSasiNo" ErrorMessage="Enter number characters only (8 or 17)" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]{8})|([0-9]{17})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

these are not working for me.

Where i miss in code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one mistake in your `RegularExpressionValidator`. Try removing one `"` from `ValidationExpression="^\d{8}$|^\d{17}$""`

See the updated code:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSasiNo" runat="server" Width="250px" MaxLength="17"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="zorunlu" ValidationGroup="kaskoTeklifSayfasi" Display="Dynamic" ID="rangevalidator1" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtSasiNo" ErrorMessage="Enter number characters only (8 or 17)" ValidationExpression="^\d{8}$|^\d{17}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSasiNo" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="kaskoTeklifSayfasi" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSasiNo" CssClass="zorunlu">Please enter Number.</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

It is working.

Comment: this is perfect answer :)

Comment: I am sorry to ask again how can i control numeric and text character (i only check digits here i also want to check text character) thanks

Comment: @Richard: I didn't get you, can you explain more

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146923/regularexpressionvalidator-check-digits-and-a-z/29147017?noredirect=1#comment46516565_29147017

Comment: I guess you got the answer :)