# RegularExpressionValidator check digits and A-Z

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Html:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSasiNo" runat="server" MaxLength="17" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="zorunlu" ValidationGroup="kaskoTeklifSayfasi" Display="Dynamic" ID="rangevalidator1" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtSasiNo" ErrorMessage="Text must be 8 or 17." ValidationExpression="^\d{8}$|^\d{17}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSasiNo" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="kaskoTeklifSayfasi" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSasiNo" CssClass="zorunlu">Please Enter Text .</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**Question:**

I have ValidationExpression as below

```
^\d{8}$|^\d{17}$
```

This only checks character number for digits.**How can i also check A-Z  characters ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want 0-9 and A-Z with length 8 or 17 to be valid:

```
^[0-9A-Z]{8}$|^[0-9A-Z]{17}$
```

**update:**

to enable all alphanumeric characters 0-9, a-z and A-Z use:

```
^[0-9A-Za-z]{8}$|^[0-9A-Za-z]{17}$
```

Comment: it works for big letters not small letters (a,b,c) it works for (A,B,C)

Comment: .. as you said check A-Z characters - just add small letters if you want to enable them too ^[0-9A-Za-z]{8}$|^[0-9A-Za-z]{17}$